# How to setup Git Linux server for Windows domain clients via SSH?

Tags: git, gitolite

Is this combination possible?

- Server: Git on Linux
- Clients: Windows
- Authentication: Windows domain credentials
- Transport protocol: SSH

If yes how would this be accomplished?

Comment: Why ssh? Usually, Windows credentials can also be registered in an LDAP, which means you can have an Apache server with LDAP authentication. In that case, https is enough. Kerberos would be used only if you are after SSO (Single Sign On) and don't want the users to enter their username/password. If so, then Dennis's answer (+1) is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible if you set up your linux server to user kerberos authentication to authenticate clients against the same active directory infrastructure as the windows clients.

Haven't tried it though, and never heard of anyone doing it. But git doesn't impose any restrictions on how the SSH connection should work, so as long as the windows SSH client can provide kerberos credentials, and the linux server can consume them, there's no reason it cannot be made to work.